# @After teardown, sleep 100ms, tests all passed

Tags: java, junit, mockito, teardown

When I run all tests with idea, it will randomly fail, but when I insert the following code in tearDown function:

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

all tests will pass! I don't know why, could anyone can help me explain it?

Comment: It's clearly some sort of timing issue, but we can't know more than that without seeing the failing code.

Comment: sorry, I can't add code for you... this is company's code

Comment: If you can create a sort of a simplified, sanitized version that you can post here, that would be good. Trying to create it may even help you fix the problem yourself! Otherwise, there is unfortunately not enough to go on here for us to help.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question afterwards. Start by including a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as currently there is way too little information which makes answering impossible.

Answer (score 0):

`tearDown()` runs after each method in your test class. So you introduce a pause between the tests with the main thread, during which some parallel cleanup can happen in other threads. You should change your methods so that they end after all cleanup has completed in all their threads. Other threads might also be involved in some of the classes that are involved in the tests.